# Question on Excel ifs statement using multiple matches

Tags: excel, if-statement, match

Hopefully this is simple syntax. I want to write an Ifs statement that test if Cell 1 matches a cell in column A vs B vs C ect (these are all in different sheets). If it does the output if true is going to be A B or C in a third column that can be used as a region column.

However when I write this it only ever tests the first condition. I have written the formula in two ways and tested the entire column, instead of outputting if it was a CN or US customer it just gives me the first "result if true" and the rest are #N/A not even test for the second condition. Is this a simple syntax issue?

Note: this is a test condition ideally I this will sort between 5 regions not just two.

```
=IFS(MATCH('External by Region'!B1,'External by Region (us)'!B:B,0),"US",(MATCH('External by Region'!B1,'External by Region (cn)'!B:B,0)),"CN")

=IFS(MATCH('External by Region'!B1,'External by Region (cn)'!B:B,0),"CN", MATCH('External by Region'!B1,'External by Region (us)'!B:B,0),"US")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `MATCH` does not find a match, it returns a `NA` error, which also causes `IFS` to error and terminate.

To make your formula work, handle the `MATCH` error by wrapping each `MATCH()` in `NOT(ISERROR(...))`

Eg

```
=IFS(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH('External by Region'!B1,'External by Region (us)'!B:B,0))),"US",
     NOT(ISERROR(MATCH('External by Region'!B1,'External by Region (cn)'!B:B,0))),"CN")
```